# read JSON file (localy or from web )

Tags: javascript, html

I have a map in html page ( Azure maps ) and I want to overlay json file with locations of some POI-s on this map. JSON file is [here](https://github.com/tekija/LCd/blob/master/wind-iter1.json) but I am struggling with famous CORS error - `Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing`
Here is what i tried in javascript:

```
<div>
    <head>
        <title>Point Clusters in Bubble Layer - wind</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="url://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>
    
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var map, datasource;
    
            //GeoJSON feed of all earthquakes from the past 30 days. Sourced from the USGS.
            var jsonwind = "https://github.com/tekija/LCd/blob/master/wind-iter1.json";
    
            //Find more earthquake data feeds here: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php
    
            function GetMap() {
                //Initialize a map instance.
                map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                    center: [23, 36.4],
                    zoom: 7,
                    style: 'night', 
                    view: 'Auto',
    
                    //Add your Azure Maps key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                    authOptions: {
                        authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                        subscriptionKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
                    }
                }); 
    
                //Wait until the map resources are ready.
                map.events.add('ready', function () {
    
                    //Create a data source and add it to the map.
                    datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource(null, {
                        //Tell the data source to cluster point data.
                        cluster: true,
    
                        //The radius in pixels to cluster points together.
                        clusterRadius: 45,
    
                        //The maximium zoom level in which clustering occurs.
                        //If you zoom in more than this, all points are rendered as symbols.
                        clusterMaxZoom: 15 
                    });
                    map.sources.add(datasource);
                    
                    //Create a bubble layer for rendering clustered data points.
                    var clusterBubbleLayer = new atlas.layer.BubbleLayer(datasource, null, {
                        //Scale the size of the clustered bubble based on the number of points in the cluster.
                        radius: [
                            'step',
                            ['get', 'point_count'],
                            20,         //Default of 20 pixel radius.
                            100, 30,    //If point_count >= 100, radius is 30 pixels.
                            750, 40     //If point_count >= 750, radius is 40 pixels.
                        ],
           
                        //Change the color of the cluster based on the value on the point_cluster property of the cluster.
                        color: [
                            'step',
                            ['get', 'point_count'],
                            'rgba(0,255,0,0.8)',            //Default to green. 
                            100, 'rgba(255,255,0,0.8)',     //If the point_count >= 100, color is yellow.
                            750, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)'        //If the point_count >= 100, color is red.
                        ],
                        strokeWidth: 0,
                        filter: ['has', 'point_count'] //Only rendered data points which have a point_count property, which clusters do.
                    });
    
                    //Add mouse events to change the mouse cursor when hovering over a cluster.
                    map.events.add('mouseenter', clusterBubbleLayer, function () {
                        map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    });
    
                    map.events.add('mouseleave', clusterBubbleLayer, function () {
                        map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'grab';
                    });
    
                    //Add the clusterBubbleLayer and two additional layers to the map.
                    map.layers.add([
                        clusterBubbleLayer,
    
                        //Create a symbol layer to render the count of locations in a cluster.
                        new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                            iconOptions: {
                                image: 'none' //Hide the icon image.
                            },
                            textOptions: {
                                textField: ['get' , 'point_count_abbreviated'],
                                offset: [0, 0.4]
                            }
                        }),
    
                        //Create a layer to render the individual locations.
                        new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                            filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']] //Filter out clustered points from this layer.
                        })
                    ]);
    
                    //Retrieve a GeoJSON data set and add it to the data source. 
                    datasource.importDataFromUrl(jsonwind);
                });
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="GetMap()">
        <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:200%;min-width: width 600px;;height:800px;"></div>
    
</div>
```

Is it possible to load this data from local computer via relative path?
How can I load data from web address?
Since I am novice in JS, I did some research and on some sources I found that importing JSONs from local files is not possible.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it's the whole issue but the url you're using is to the Github **site** which returns html, not json. If you want the "raw" file, you can get it here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/wind-iter1.json.

Comment: This is great. This raw data hyperlink solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear :)